# What exactly does "fap" mean? [NSFW]

Tags: meaning, slang, internet, offensive-language

Sorry for the ridiculous question, but I can't understand the difference between *fap* and *masturbation*. Does *fap* mean the whole progress?

Comment: Sorry but it seems like a puerile joke question to me.  But I don't know what to flag it as...

Comment: I'm just not a native English speaker.

Comment: I've never heard the word *fap* before, so I am speculatively tagging this [tag:british-english].

Comment: In case vulgar slang is considered too dangerous for this site, you can always find answers to questions like these at urbandictionary.com. Be warned, though: there is a *lot* of crude language on that site.

Comment: Also be warned that it contains a lot of stuff that is just plain made up.

Comment: The only time I've seen this word was when I (regrettably) looked up the foul bachelor frog meme. I guessed what it meant from context, and then tried to block it from memory. (formerly sheltered teen speaking)

Comment: Funny how when we don't know a word someone asks about, we assume it must be from the other side of the Atlantic (both ways round). No, it's not British.

Comment: Is _[NFSW]_ necessary, in the title?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Depends where you work :)

Comment: @ColinFine - I must admit that the word sounded quite British to me (I speak American English as my adopted main language, but I'm ESL and **started out** learning Her Majesty's version for many years before switching to American version)

Comment: I think it emerged on internet forums, so I guess that makes it a citizen of the world.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the sake of giving this a fun answer in case you're asking in earnest...

[*Fap*](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/fap) is an internet neologism, an [onomatopoeic intransitive verb](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fap) referring to the act of male masturbation, whose sound is imitative of the associated slapping of testicles against the body. *Fapping* refers *exclusively* to male masturbation; female masturbation is (in context and by association, but very [rarely in practice](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22paffing%22)) referred to as *paffing* or *squishing*. Reportedly it has its origins in the Japanese-language [comic sound effects](http://www.lolikon.org/misc/soundfx.html) used in manga, in reference to the same act.

Comment: +1 but i'd like to see a reference that it comes from manga

Comment: @trideceth12: How about the first reference I put?

Comment: On the chans, female masturbation is called "Schlicking"

Comment: @chris: Right you are. Presumably that's true anywhere chan slang is common, such as ED.

Comment: A possibly helpful analogy: *fap* is to masturbation as *nom* is to eating.

Answer (score 4):

'fap' is a slang term. We have many slang terms in English, some more familiar (or crude) than others, for masturbation. They all signify the general, uh, "process," if you will.

Comment: Anything can be used as a euphemism, though. I particularly like the *Xing the old Y* construction, for example, *stranking the old wollydingle*. Doesn't mean a thing, but you know just what it means.

Comment: That construction inspires a lot of clever (and hilarious) invention; even a certain intonation does the trick. Palmdale, for example, is a small town in the greater Los Angeles area. It doesn't have nearly as many visitors as people claim.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the word *fap* has existed in English for a long time meaning drunk to the point of befuddlement, as in Shakespeare's "Merry Wives of Windsor":

> Bardolph: Why, sir, for my part I say the gentleman had drunk himself out of his five sentences.
>
> Sir Hugh Evans: It is his five senses: fie, what the ignorance is!
>
> Bardolph: And being fap, sir, was, as they say, cashiered; and so conclusions passed the careires.

In it's more recent meaning that refers to masturbation, its usage is somewhat different. It is onomatopœtic of course, and when used it is normally intended to have a comic false obliqueness (it pretends to be subtle, when really it's less subtle than just saying "masturbate"). So one might say "fap, fap, fap" meaning "I am going to think about this later while masturbating", as a crude joke.

It's popularity is generally credited to the web-comic "Sexy Losers", (considerably more NSFW than this page, google if you want to find it), whose author has said:

> It was pulled from the Viz translation of Heartbroken Angels. Although there were a number of sounds the translator used for masturbation (there’s a lot of that going on in that comic), I chose the word fap as it came from a particular strip that had god masturbating.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike masturbation, fapping is, exclusively, the auto-erotic stimulation of the penis. Fapping is not used to describe intellectual, mutual, anal, or vaginal masturbation.